# Unix - df output is /var 98% but just 374mb used in du output

Tags: aix

Here is my df -g output:

```
df -g /var
Filesystem    GB blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/hd9var        3.50      0.10   98%     6376     18% /var
```

But if a enter in the mount point and issue du command, I get the following output

```
ux-zzz02:/var>du -sm .
374.38  .
ux-zzz02:/var>
```

How can this happen? I have only 374mb being used but df command says it's used 98% of 3.50gb

Comment: Sometime this happens if `du` does not have permission to enter a directory.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I have been with root user

Comment: @DaniloNeto per the note that mattdm linked to, did you delete any log files recently? Those may have been held open by existing processes.

Answer (score 1):

"lsof" is all that you need....

```
lsof | grep -i delete
```

The output will show you if some file(s) still in use have been deleted.

Regards

Comment: Notice that the user is on AIX. There is by default no `lsof` command on AIX, AFAIK.

Comment: Indeed, it's not provided directly any more; it used to be on the [AIX Toolbox for Linux Applications](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/883796#L). Per [this forum post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=668c2e09-55c7-404f-85a0-31638919f4b1), it's been removed.

Comment: As an alternative to lsof, use ```fuser -dV /var``` which also shows deleted files with open filehandles for a given mountpoint/filesystem.

Comment: `lsof` can be compiled from source, and OP had root access, so this answer might be usable.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have mount points inside /var?

When you mount something on a directory it does not matter if the directory is empty or not, it just mounts what you told it to mount. According to this you may have mounted something on a directory which was not empty and have a lot of files or just a few files that occupy a lot of space. Using `du` won't take into account those files since it will only see the files on the mounted fs, and that may be the "unjustified" discrepancy between those two commands.

Try unmounting those directories and checking if you have files there.